# Mariadb start failed in CentOS 7

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am using Mariadb (mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.40-MariaDB) in CentOS (CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406). I tried to restart Mariadb.

```
systemctl start mariadb

Job for mariadb.service failed. See 'systemctl status mariadb.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

When I checked : /var/log/mysql-error.log as suggested by 'systemctl status mariadb.service'

```
170523 10:20:10 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
170523 10:20:10 [Warning] 'THREAD_CONCURRENCY' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
170523 10:20:10 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024  max_connections: 214  table_cache: 400
170523 10:20:10 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170523 10:20:10 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170523 10:20:10 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
170523 10:20:10 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170523 10:20:11 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 15.6G
170523 10:20:11 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170523 10:20:11 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
170523 10:20:12  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
170523 10:20:13 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.40-MariaDB-36.1 started; log sequence number 5336723441509
170523 10:20:13 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
170523 10:20:13 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown variable 'extra-lsndir=/var/tmp'
170523 10:20:13 [ERROR] Aborting

170523 10:20:13  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
170523 10:20:15  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 5336723441509
170523 10:20:15 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

170523 10:20:15 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/master.compare-prices.repchecker.jp.pid ended
170523 10:21:10 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
170523 10:21:10 [Warning] 'THREAD_CONCURRENCY' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
170523 10:21:10 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024  max_connections: 214  table_cache: 400
170523 10:21:10 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170523 10:21:10 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170523 10:21:10 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
170523 10:21:10 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
170523 10:21:10 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 15.6G
170523 10:21:11 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170523 10:21:11 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
170523 10:21:12  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
170523 10:21:13 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.40-MariaDB-36.1 started; log sequence number 5336723441509
170523 10:21:13 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
170523 10:21:13 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown variable 'extra-lsndir=/var/tmp'
170523 10:21:13 [ERROR] Aborting
.
.
.
.
```

PS: /var/lib/mysql directory is owned by mysql (there is one more directory mysql~ which is empty)

> drwxr-xr-x  8 mysql   mysql   4096 May 23 11:05 mysql
>
> drwxr-xr-x. 3 mysql   mysql     26 Feb  4  2015 mysql~

Please provide some suggestion. How can I restart my mariadb, I have important database under mariadb.

Comment: Looking at the logs it seems 150204 which is old date. Please provide latest log. Use `tail` command to show that.

Comment: @Avi , I edited it in question. Please check new log.

Comment: check if you don't already have a mysql process running `pgrep mysql`.

Comment: @Louis Loudog Trottier No, no mysql process is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the last line of error

`[ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: unknown variable 'extra-lsndir=/var/tmp'`

It is clear that this variable is not known so try to comment it from `/etc/my.cnf` and try again.

```
# Point the following paths to different dedicated disks
tmpdir         = /var/tmp
extra-lsndir = /var/tmp    ------> Comment this line 
target-dir=/var/tmp
```

I hope it will help.